# How to install Ubuntu on Android phone (HTC Desire)

Tags: installation, ubuntu-for-android

I want to install Ubuntu on Android device. The detail of my handset is as under :-

- HTC Desire
- A8181
- RAM 512
  Processor - 1GHz

... where can i find ubuntu OS for my android HTC desire?

Answer (score 2):

***You have three choices:***

(1.) **No Risk:** You can wait until this is better supported, and easy to install.

---

(2.) **Medium Risk:** Try **Ubuntu Touch** on an *ASUS Nexus 7 ..*

### [How to install](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) -- [Release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes) -- [Using the device](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/UsingTheDevice)

---

(3.) **High Risk:** Try installing (on your device).

### [wiki.Ubuntu > Touch > Devices > **bravo**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/bravo)  (aka *HTC Desire*)

***NOTE: This appears to be work-in-progress.***

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu mobile version hasn't been released yet. If you go to ubuntu's home page, you can sign up to a mailing list to be notified when it comes out.

It is possible to install ubuntu anyway, but you will no longer have a phone, and it will likely drain the battery much faster than when using android. You will need to back up your phone, "root" it (android version of jailbreak), and then use the ubuntu installer app from the app store. I've looked in to doing this, but haven't done this before, and this isn't the place to ask about it. You will have to search for a forum or something to guide you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to root your phone, you can try [this app.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid&hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

I tried Linux on Htc Desire HD. Kali and some Arch Linux. Both work perfectly under the Linux Deploy at NVC. De facto its totaly useless. Apparently the software centre was working but without possibility of installing any apps. Lets wait for the official software to see whats going to happened

Comment: The reason the software center was useless is because your phone probably has an ARM processor and most of the software and dependencies are only compiled for x86.